# ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 - Make controller unaccessible outside is own area

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I am developing an APS.NET Core Mvc and I have an admin area that represents a backoffice.

One of the controllers that I have is a BlogController that is inside Admin area, but when I go to route:

/admin/blog or /blog

I am redirected to the same controller.
What can I do to prevent controller from being accessed outside it's area?

Startup.cs Endpoints code:

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {

                

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                    name: "Admin",
                    areaName: "Admin",
                    pattern: "{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                    );

       }
```

And Blog Controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;

namespace BenecarSite.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    [Area("Admin")]
    public class BlogController : Controller
    {
        // GET: BlogController
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Best Regards

Comment: Try mapping your "admin" route before your "default" route.

Comment: @mxmissile Thanks for the comment but doesn´t work. I will try with something more generic in the "admin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{area:...}` can be used as a token in route templates if url space is uniform across all areas:

```
       app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Admin",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        });
```

In the preceding code, **exists applies a constraint that the route must match an area.** Using `{area:...}` with `MapControllerRoute`:

Is the least complicated mechanism to adding routing to areas.
Matches all controllers with the `[Area("Area name")]` attribute.

> Test result

[image]

There are more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-area-route).